# div with two child divs causes unwanted vertical scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I want to define a vertical layout with two divs, a small fixed one at the top and a dynamically sized one below such that the bottom one will always fill the screen, nothing more and nothing less. So I tried defining it as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="contents">
  <div id="nav" style="width: 100%; height: 20px;"></div> 
  <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I test this html in Firefox it adds a vertical scrollbar. It seems like the container is given the 100% height of the window without allowing for the 20px div above it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `calc(100% - 20px)` on the `height` of `#container` - this subtracts the 20px from the 100% for the `#container` height, so that the two heights sum up to 100% of their parent container. However, if you use percentage heights, you have to add them to all parents / elements on higher levels which don't have a fixed height setting, like I did it in the snippet below, so that the elements have a reference for their percentage values.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#contents {
  height: 100%;
}

#nav {
  height: 20px;
  background: blue
}

#container {
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div id="contents">
  <div id="nav"></div>
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```